# Typeinfo with record type does not work at runtime

Tags: delphi, rtti, typeinfo

I have a little problem with compilation under Delphi:

```
function T_QS2ProcessMailbox.PutRec<T>(const aID: T_Barcode; var aRec: T;const aTxt: String): Boolean;
var
  FA: T_FahrauftragRec absolute aRec;
  LP: T_LagerpackungRec absolute aRec;
begin
  init_Rec;
  Rec.ID        := aID;
  Rec.EventTime := Now;
  Rec.Text      := aTxt;
  if TypeInfo(T_LagerpackungRec) = TypeInfo(T) then
  begin
    Rec.RecType := C_QS_TYPE_TLAGERPACKUNGREC;
    Rec.FA      := FA;
  end
  else
    if Typeinfo(T) = Typeinfo(T_LagerpackungRec) then
    begin
      Rec.RecType := C_QS_TYPE_TFAHRAUFTRAGREC;
      Rec.LP      := LP;
    end
    else
      Rec.RecType := C_QS_TYPE_TEXT;
  Send_TraceMsg(ClassName + '.PutRec Type=' + IntToStr(Rec.RecType));
  Result        := PutRec(Rec);
end;
```

It compiles fine without errors, messages, or hints. But it is compiled without `if` statements. You can look at it in the picture - this code without compilations marker

[image]

I do not understand why.

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `if` statements can be resolved at compile time, so only ever 1 of them will be actually compiled for any given value of `T`. (In other word, the compiled code will never execute any `if` for this function).

I can imagine 2 reasons for seeing only 1 compilation marker.  Either your application will only ever use 1 of the `if` statements, or the IDE will map the compilation marker of all the `if` statements to the same line (I find this last one unlikely, but I've seen stranger things in the IDE).

Another possibility is that your 2nd `if` should read

```
if Typeinfo(T) = Typeinfo(T_FahrauftragRec) then
```

instead of

```
if Typeinfo(T) = Typeinfo(T_LagerpackungRec) then
```

Answer (score 0):

`Typeinfo()` is a *compiler intrinsic function* in XE7 and later, and thus is available for the compiler to evaluate at compile-time <sup>1</sup>.  And since the type of `T` is a Generic that is also known to the compiler, the compiler can directly evaluate your `if`s and any blocks that evaluate to `False` and would never be executed at runtime are simply omitted from the final executable altogether.  That is why you don't see any debugger points on them.

<sup>1: but only in the specific case where `TypeInfo(T)` is used in an `if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(X)` statement inside a Generic method. Other uses of `TypeInfo()` are not similarly inlined at compile-time.</sup>

This is **normal behavior**, and is what you WANT to have happened, as it produces slimmer and more efficient runtime code.

When your other code calls `PutRec<T_FahrauftragRec>(...)` then `T` will be `T_FahrauftragRec` and thus `TypeInfo(T_LagerpackungRec) = TypeInfo(T_FahrauftragRec)` will evaluate as False.

Likewise, when calling `PutRec<T_LagerpackungRec>(...)` then `T` will be `T_LagerpackungRec` and thus `TypeInfo(T_FahrauftragRec) = TypeInfo(T_LagerpackungRec)` will evaluate as False.

And so on for any other type you pass to `T`.

Also, you have a bug in your code.  Your second `if` statement:

```
if Typeinfo(T) = Typeinfo(T_LagerpackungRec) then
```

Should be this instead:

```
if Typeinfo(T) = Typeinfo(T_FahrauftragRec) then
```

Comment: Sorry, but my question was about other things: why the snippet with 'if-statement' was ignored with compiler.  I did test in other code wit PutRec<T_FahrauftragRec>().

Comment: @svd71 "*why the snippet with 'if-statement' was ignored with compiler*" - I already covered that. Read my answer again more carefully. You accepted Ken's answer, which basically told you the same thing I did. The compiler is able to determine that the `if` statements won't do anything at runtime so it optimizes them out. In your screenshot, neither `if` covers `T_FahrauftragRec`, so both `if`s are omitted when calling `PutRec<T_FahrauftragRec>()`.